# Changing keyboard layout of NoMachine client

Tags: keyboard-layout, nomachine

I'm connecting to a Red Hat Linux 5 host using the NoMachine Windows Client. When using the client, the keys I press appear as though I'm using a QWERTY keyboard, even though Windows has been set to use the bépo layout.

I've tried changing the Linux host to use bépo but there were issues and I gave up because I figured I'd mostly be using it through NoMachine anyway. I'm not sure if the host needs any keyboard changes in order to configure NoMachine − some of the things I was reading made it sound like there's some kind of resolution about keyboards made between the host and client, rather than the client just sending characters.

Anyway, how do I change the layout for the client? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated NoMachine to v4 and found I can now change the keyboard layout of the host during my session, seeing the keys appear on the host as though they're converted from hardware signals to actual characters at the host, rather than the client. I'll have to figure out how to enable my layout in Red Hat :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using xmodmap and NoMachine 4, so the keys seem to get transmitted as qwerty, then get mapped to my preferred layout (bépo) by RHEL once I start the session and awkwardly tell xmodmap to start. Thankfully the bépo authors had an xmodmap file available for me that was mostly correct.